# What indexes would improve the speed of this query?

Tags: postgresql

```
Select link_id, date_trunc('day', inserted_at), 
count(*) from clicks 
where 
previous_click_id is null 
and link_workspace_id = 2 
group by 
link_id, date_trunc('day', inserted_at)
```

Output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=153356.84..163584.13 rows=129848 width=24) (actual time=1315.303..1783.331 rows=25234 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: link_id, (date_trunc('day'::text, inserted_at))"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=153356.84..155507.88 rows=860419 width=16) (actual time=1315.280..1645.578 rows=879836 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: link_id, (date_trunc('day'::text, inserted_at))"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 22296kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on clicks  (cost=0.00..53835.41 rows=860419 width=16) (actual time=0.054..741.964 rows=879836 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((previous_click_id IS NULL) AND (link_workspace_id = 2))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 418485"
"Planning time: 0.204 ms"
"Execution time: 1794.119 ms"
```

Comment: What type is inserted_at?  If it is timestamptz, then truncating it to date will not be immutable, as the answer will depend on the timezone you have your connection set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular index scan won't help, since you are retrieving most of the table.

But you should increase `work_mem` to get a faster in-memory sort.

You could experiment with a covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON clicks (link_workspace_id)
   INCLUDE (link_id, inserted_at)
   WHERE previous_click_id IS NULL;

VACUUM clicks;
```

You need to keep the table well vacuumed to get an index only scan.

Comment: Wouldn't something like a partial index `ON link_workspace_id, link_id, date_trunc('day', inserted_at) WHERE previous_click_id is null` help?

Comment: A covering index may make it faster if the table is wide. The partial index would help in that case.